# Center and make image go over screen edges - Ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, web

I am trying to build an application home page with Ionic and am having trouble centering an image while increasing it's size. This is what my "image header" currently looks like:

[image: Current]

Ideally it would look like this:

[image: Desired]

Here is the html and css for the related elements:

HTML

```
<div id="header-image-container">
  <img class="curved-img" src="../../assets//img/arctic-aurora-aurora-borealis-258112.jpg" alt="Header image">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.curved-img {
  margin-top: -30%;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
  max-width: 50rem;
}
```

Is there a way I can center the image in respect to the main page view while ignoring the limits of the view?

Thank you!

Comment: Yep. Place the image as `background-image` of the entire view with `background-size:cover`. as in: `.yourContainer {background: url('path/to/image') no-repeat center center /cover}`

Comment: Thank you! I removed the image element and changed to what you described. I still have the issue of not being able to increase the width of the container div without it lining up with the left side limit of the view and bleeding out of the right. In essence, I want to be able to increase the size of the div and it remain centered within the view.

Comment: You could change `center center` to `center top` or `10% 80%` or whatever makes sense to you, but without a [mcve] it's impossible to give you better advice. Anyway, in such cases the best thing to do is just crop the image to the minimal necessary size covering all possible sizes of your header. Bigger image means more bandwidth, slower app.